# What is the relation between strength of a base and the thermal stability of its salts?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, stability, alkaline-earth-metals

In *Concise Inorganic Chemistry, $5^{th}$ edition*, by JD Lee, while discussing oxides and hydroxides of Group $2$ metals, it has been stated that:

> The increase in basic strength is illustrated by the temperatures at which the carbonates decompose.

What is the basis for this statement? How does the fact that carbonate thermal stability of Group $2$ carbonates increases down the group related to increased basic strength? If I am not mistaken, the explanation for increased stability of carbonates is related to increase in lattice energy due to high coordination number facilitated by larger cation. On the other hand, basic strength should be determined by the $\Delta H_r$ of the reaction:

$$\ce{M(OH)_2}(aq)\to \ce{M^{2+}}(aq)+\ce{2OH^{-}}(aq)$$
Clearly, a high lattice energy for base should decrease the magnitude of $\Delta H_r$, but it seems that this factor is compensated for by other factors. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: In ma opinion there is no correlation between the basic strength of hydroxides and the decomposition temperature of the carbonates. Or : if you find such a correlation, it would probably be the result of a coincidence.

Comment: Even I was surprised by this claim, but the author mentions this multiple times while discussing group $1$ and group $2$ salts. He even goes so far as to explain the higher stability of Group $1$ carbonates using higher basic strength of alkali bases.

Comment: Why compare carbonates and hydroxides ? Why not choose sulfates ? or nitrates ? I would be pleased to discuss this point with the author. Why not ? ?

Comment: Even so, does the statement: "stronger bases form stabler salts" have any basis?

Comment: Also, I'd like to add this: In the following section, on sulphates, the author says- " In the same way as with the stability and thermal decomposition of the carbonates, the more basic the metal is, the more stable the sulphate is. This is shown by the temperatures at which decomposition occurs".

Comment: There can be correlation between Arrhenius basicity of $\ce{M(OH)2}$ and Lewis acidity of $\ce{M^2+}$  which affects salt stability. More acidic cation will have bigger tendency to bond with the anion as the Lewis base and eventually steal $\ce{O^2-}$ to form oxide.

Comment: @Poutnik OK, but how does this answer my question?

Comment: Comments do not answer questions. If they did, they would be posted as answers.// Level of polarization of anions by cations has impact on anion thermal stability.

Comment: And how is defined (or measured) the basic strength of hydroxides ? Has it anything to do with solubility ?